# Unity implementation in Swift 3 Project: Crash on app launch - MetadataCache::Initialize()

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, swift3, crash, integration

Hello fellow programmers,

I need to implement an exported Unity project to my native Swift project, so I followed the instructions of this tutorial:

https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5

Unfortunately, the app crashes on app launch. I took a screenshot of my debug navigator:

[image]

I found this thread and followed every advice, but I cannot get it running. I would be very glad to see a working example:

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/il2cpp-anyone-else-seeing-metadatacache-initialize-crashes-sometimes-when-the-game-starts.383145/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats a memory crash. please run your app on instruments and look for memory leaks and heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. The tutorial says to remove the references of all ".h files" in Unity/Classes/Native/, but I accidently deleted all of them.